# Unable to mock session with Emberfire

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm writing a very basic acceptance test against a route that has both admin and non-admin capabilities. My test makes an assertion that if I'm coming to the app for the first time, I don't see logged in capabilities. In my application, I'm using `password` authentication as follows:

```
this.get('session').open('firebase', {
  provider: 'password',
  email: email,
  password: password
});
```

I have found that when I am not authenticated in the app, then run the acceptance test, it passes. However, if I then log in on the app, then run tests, my assertion fails because the session is restored, when I think it shouldn't be. Here's the test:

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'app/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
import destroyApp from '../helpers/destroy-app';
import replaceAppRef from '../helpers/replace-app-ref';
import replaceFirebaseAppService from '../helpers/replace-firebase-app-service';
import stubFirebase from '../helpers/stub-firebase';
import unstubFirebase from '../helpers/unstub-firebase';
import { emptyApplication } from '../helpers/create-test-ref';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | index', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    stubFirebase();
    application = startApp();
    replaceFirebaseAppService(application, { });
    replaceAppRef(application, emptyApplication());
  },
  afterEach: function() {
    unstubFirebase();
    destroyApp(application);
  }
});

test('empty app - not authenticated', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), page.url, 'on the correct page');

    // this works if there's no session - fails otherwise
    assert.notOk(page.something.isVisible, 'cannot do something');
  });
});
```

I think `replaceFirebaseAppService` should be overriding the `torii-adapter` but it doesn't appear to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using:

```
Ember      : 2.7.0
Ember Data : 2.7.0
Firebase   : 3.2.1
EmberFire  : 2.0.1
jQuery     : 2.2.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at Emberfire closer, `replaceFirebaseAppService` is trying to replace the torii adapter registered at `torii-adapter:firebase` when it was being registered by my application as `torii-adapter:application`.

What I ended up doing was basically replicating `replaceFirebaseAppService` in my own helper:

```
import stubFirebase from '../helpers/stub-firebase';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
import replaceAppRef from '../helpers/replace-app-ref';
import createOfflineRef from './create-offline-ref';

export default function startFirebaseApp(fixtures = { }) {
  stubFirebase();
  let application = startApp();

  // override default torii-adapter
  const mock = { };
  application.register('service:firebaseMock', mock, {
    instantiate: false,
    singleton: true
  });
  application.inject('torii-provider:application', 'firebaseApp', 'service:firebaseMock');
  application.inject('torii-adapter:application', 'firebaseApp', 'service:firebaseMock');

  // setup any fixture data and return instance
  replaceAppRef(application, createOfflineRef(fixtures));
  return application;
}
```

This prevents the torii-adapter from resolving any session data that I may have from using my application. Then I can use the provided torii helper to mock my session where I need it:

```
// torii helper
import { stubValidSession } from 'app/tests/helpers/torii';

// mock a valid session
stubValidSession(application, { });
```

Hope that saves someone else some time.